# Updating a table with PHP and MYSQL 

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php require("inc_connect.php"); ?>
<h1 align="center">Farris Website</h1>
<hr width="1000">
<p align="center">

<table align="center" width="1000" border="3" bordercolor="#0066FF" >
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
        <form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['id']); ?>">
          <p><strong>Enter Name:</strong>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <br />
            ID: 
            <label for="select"></label>
            <select name="id">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
                while($output = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
                echo "<option value=\"{$output['id']}\">{$output['id']}</option>";}
            ?>
            </select>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update!">
          </p>
        </form></td>
        <td width="300" align="left" valign="top"><?php include("inc_output.php"); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</p>
```

The above is the index page ...

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sel_database = mysql_select_db("test");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] );
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

$query = "UPDATE test SET name='{$name}'";
if($run = mysql_query($query)){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
    }else{mysql_error();}


?>
```

And this is the page that processes the form.

The problem is that the record won't update if i set the id={$_GET['id']}

and if I remove that part it updates all the rows.

So updating according to id ...

Thanks in Advance

FarrisFahad

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but you should read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), especially if you are going to connect to MySQL as the root user (don't do that).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form action to

```
<form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>">
```

Also, doing an echo of $query might help debug your problem.

Comment: Actually, you already have a reference to "id" in your form so update your form action to just "ex_update.php". Then change your php code to $id = (int) $_POST['id'];

Answer (score 0):

First, just be aware of SQL Injection - your code is wide open to it. See http://bobby-tables.com/

### PHP Code

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$sel_database = mysql_select_db("test");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["name"] );
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

$query = "UPDATE test SET name='{$name}' WHERE id = {$id}";
if($run = mysql_query($query)){
  header("location: index.php");
  exit;
}else{
  # In production, don't show raw errors to users - log them to a file and
  # present the user with a generic "There was a problem with the database"
  # error. Or people can start sniffing for vulnerabilities in your site.
  echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

### Page

```
<?php

require("inc_connect.php");

?>
<h1 align="center">Farris Website</h1>
<hr width="1000">
<p align="center">
  <table align="center" width="1000" border="3" bordercolor="#0066FF" >
    <tr>
      <td><form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>">
        <p><strong>Enter Name:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="name"><br />
          <label for="select">ID:</label>
          <select name="id" id="select">
<?php 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
  $run = mysql_query($query);
  while( $r = mysql_fetch_array($run) ){
    # I always use short, single character, variables when in loops.
    # Saves alot of characters and potential confusion.
    echo "          <option value='{$r['id']}'>{$r['id']}</option>\n";
  }
?>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update!">
        </p>
      </form></td>
      <td><?php include("inc_output.php"); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
```

Comment: I just checked, and there is no problem with the query when I UPDATE without WHERE id={$id}. but I would like to update it according to the id,

Comment: OK, three things then. 1) Can you share the full SQL statement (with WHERE...) here? 2) Does the `id` field exist in the table? 3) What does the `mysql_error()` display?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to update that record which is selected from your dropdown. Moreover u have set your form method to POST. So you should try following:

```
<form name="update" method="post" action="ex_update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($_POST['id']); ?>">
```